# number theory polynomial congruences

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $f(x)$, $g(x)$ be polynomials with integer coefficients. If $f(x)\equiv g(x)\pmod{n}$ then what condition must $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ have to satisfy in order for this statement to be true?
If possible please give an example

Comment: Very similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163490/congruent-polynomials).

Comment: thanks for the link

Comment: The answer is complicated because $\mathbb Z_n[X]$ is not a domain.

Comment: Perhaps the question is too general. Did you try any example yourself?